# Appwrite succesfullyu installed but a new directory isnt created

Tags: docker, docker-compose, appwrite

I have installed Appwrite. But a new directory conating the docker-compose.yml and .env has not been created.  The terminal is giving a sucess message. Docker is also working properly.

I installed appwrite through following commands:

```
    docker run -it --rm \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    --volume "$(pwd)"/appwrite:/usr/src/code/appwrite:rw \
    --entrypoint="install" \
    appwrite/appwrite:0.13.4
```

Have a look of my terminal screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed Appwrite before on this machine? If you have, then it isn't something to be concerned about. Notice how your docker compose is pointing to /usr/src/code/appwrite/docker-compose.yml? This is probably your past installation, and your local Docker volumes still point there.

Everything will still work correctly :)